# Why to use Cstring over wchar_t

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a code in which Cstring and wchar_t both are used. I think i can do the same work with wchar_t instead of Cstring, so why to use Cstring.

in m_szChargeType and m_szConfirmedChargeType i have A.
At first my code was

```
wchar_t m_szChargeType[LEN_CHARGE_TYPE];
wchar_t m_szConfirmedChargeType[LEN_CHARGE_TYPE];
LoadString(GetResourceInstance(),IDS_MS_CI_TYPEA,m_szChargeType,LEN_CHARGE_TYPE);//      fills value A in m_szChargeType
LoadString(GetResourceInstance(),IDS_MS_CI_TYPEA,m_szConfirmedChargeType,LEN_CHARGE_TYPE);        // fills value A in m_szConfirmedChargeType   
CString strSpace(IDS_MS_SPACE); //IDS_MS_SPACE has a space in rc file and IDS_MS_TYPE   have rate in ini file
CString strType(IDS_MS_TYPE);
strSpace += strType;
wsprintf(m_szChargeType, _T("%s%s"), m_szChargeType, strSpace);
wsprintf(m_szConfirmedChargeType, _T("%s%s"), m_szConfirmedChargeType, strSpace);
```

the result in m_szChargeType and m_szConfirmedChargeType was A0, but expected was A Rate

then i did

```
wchar_t strSpace[LEN_CHARGE_TYPE];
wchar_t strType[LEN_CHARGE_TYPE];
LoadString(GetResourceInstance(),IDS_MS_SPACE,strSpace,LEN_CHARGE_TYPE);
LoadString(GetResourceInstance(),IDS_MS_TYPE,strType,LEN_CHARGE_TYPE);
wsprintf(m_szChargeType, _T("%s%s%s"), m_szChargeType, strSpace, strType);
wsprintf(m_szConfirmedChargeType, _T("%s%s%s"), m_szConfirmedChargeType, strSpace, strType);
```

it worked fine. and the output was same as expected A RATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CString` is a class, and so it provides functionality. `wchar_t` is just a basic type, and it represents a *single* wide character. I'm assuming you were talking about `wchar_t*`.

It's *like* asking why you should use `std::string` over `char*`.

Comment: in my case Cstring is woking fine in every module but one, so i replaced it and used wchar_t, and the code runs fine. so are there any cases where Cstring doesn't work properly and wchar_t works?

Comment: @Tejendra yes, in cases when it's misused. Did you replace it with `wchar_t` or with `wchar_t*`?

Comment: @Tejendra ok in this case, you're misusing the CString, by feeding it to `wsprintf` directly, when you should use `GetBuffer` - `wsprintf(m_szChargeType, _T("%s%s"), m_szChargeType, strSpace.GetBuffer);`. Note that you didn't replace CString with `wchar_t`, but with `wchar_t[]`, which is an array.